# yearly spaced dates on the exact same date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to have the exact same date every year from an end date to next one from today. For example if my end is "20251220", I would like to get the following list of dates
"20211220","20221220","20231220","20241220". However, if it was "20250220" I only need "20220220","20230220","20240220" as we already passed February. I tried to a simple loop by myself (see below) where I then would check at then end if first date is in the past. But I think there must be a build in function to do this, via pandas or dateutil etc.
I've tried this:

```
In [455]: import datetime as dt

In [456]: end = dt.date(2025, 12,20)

In [457]: start = dt.date(dt.datetime.today().year, end.month,end.d)

In [458]: periods = end.year-start.year

In [461]: l = [dt.date(start.year + i, 12, 20) for i in range(0,periods)]

In [462]: l
Out[462]: 
[datetime.date(2021, 12, 20),
 datetime.date(2022, 12, 20),
 datetime.date(2023, 12, 20),
 datetime.date(2024, 12, 20),
 datetime.date(2025, 12, 20)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea with list comprehension:

```
import datetime as dt

end = dt.date(2025, 12,20)
today = dt.datetime.today()
l = [end.replace(year=i) 
     for i in range(today.year, end.year)
     if end.replace(year=i) > today.date()]
print (l)
[datetime.date(2021, 12, 20), 
 datetime.date(2022, 12, 20), 
 datetime.date(2023, 12, 20),
 datetime.date(2024, 12, 20)]
```

---

```
import datetime as dt

end = dt.date(2025, 2,20)
today = dt.datetime.today()
l = [end.replace(year=i) 
     for i in range(today.year, end.year) 
     if end.replace(year=i) > today.date()]
print (l)
[datetime.date(2022, 2, 20), datetime.date(2023, 2, 20), datetime.date(2024, 2, 20)]
```

Solution working with `29 February`:

```
import datetime as dt

end = dt.date(2028, 2,29)
today = dt.datetime.today()
l = [(end + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=i)).date() 
     for i in range(today.year, end.year) 
     if (end + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=i)) > today]
print (l)
[datetime.date(2022, 2, 28),
 datetime.date(2023, 2, 28), 
 datetime.date(2024, 2, 29), 
 datetime.date(2025, 2, 28), 
 datetime.date(2026, 2, 28), 
 datetime.date(2027, 2, 28)]
```

Comment: Again thanks for your answer. One small question. If I want to go back fixed amount of month, could we adjust your method? like `pd.offsets.DateOffset(month=i*12/freq))` where `freq` is between one and 12. 1 meaning going back yearly and 12 going back on a monthly basis. But I'm not sure how to adjust the looping range for `i`

Comment: @math You think change `month=i*12/freq` to `month=int(i*12/freq)`? Because there is necessary integers.

Comment: exactly, my point is, I would like to parameterise it so that you can say what kind of frequency you want to go back. Where frequency is a number between 1 and 12. 12  indicating yearly, and 1 indicating monthly. So 4 would mean going back quaterly. Can we adapt your example to work with such a parameter?

Comment: @math - hmmm, is possible add some data samples to question? Or better create new question?

Comment: did open a new one, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467009/moving-backwards-in-time-until-specific-dates-with-a-given-frequency-month-in

Comment: @math - I see, not so easy.