# Moving backwards in time until specific dates with a given frequency (month) in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to have a list of date every year from an end date spaced in given month amount. For example if my end is "20251220" and I have a paramter `freq` which steers the time step to go back. A value of `1` indicates yearly steps and a value of 12 indicates monthly backward steps. I would like to get the following list of dates for `freq` 1 it should
"20211220","20221220","20231220","20241220" and for `freq` 2 "20211220","20220620","20221220","20230620""20231220","20240620","20241220","20250620". However, if it was "20250220" I only need "20220220","20230220","20240220" as we already passed February in the case for `freq` 1. I tried to a simple loop by myself (see below) where I then would check at then end if first date is in the past. But I think there must be a build in function to do this, via pandas or dateutil etc. See the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432140/yearly-spaced-dates-on-the-exact-same-date/67432440?noredirect=1#comment119245610_67432440) without the `freq` paramter

Comment: did you check out dateutil's [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `date_range`, setting end date as `now` and frequency in `DateOffset`:

```
pd.date_range('20250220', 'now', freq=-pd.DateOffset(months=12//freq))[1:]
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2024-02-20', '2023-02-20', '2022-02-20'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<-1 * DateOffset: months=12>')
```

Comment: but then we would need to adjust in `pd.DateOffset(months=int(12/freq))[1:]` right?

Comment: @math Yes, exactly, if you want freq=1 to be yearly, and freq=12 to be monthly

Comment: Updated my answer to use `freq` variable as parameter